# Replacing elements of a vector

Tags: r

I have the following string:

```
string <- c("100 this is 100 test 100 string")
```

I would like to replace the 100's in the above string with elements of another vector:

```
replacement <- c(1000,2000,3000)
```

The first 100 of string should be replace by 1000, second 100 by 2000 and so on. The resulting string should look as follows:

```
result <- c("1000 this is 2000 test 3000 string")
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in R?

Thank you.

Ravi

Comment: So the value to be replaced is always fixed, the number of times such values occurs is always known, the number to be replaced is always alternating with text, and the length of the replacement vector always matches the number of times the value to be replaced occurs? I'm just checking on the "base assumptions" about the question.

Comment: Hi Ananda, To clarify...the value is fixed...the number of time such values occur changes from case to case...number to be replaced could be either text or other numbers as well...vector lengths are always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant, but this should do..

```
string <- c("100 this is 100 test 100 string")
temp <- unlist(strsplit(string, split = "\\s+"))
replacement <- c(1000, 2000, 3000)
temp[temp == "100"] <- replacement
result <- paste(temp, collapse = " ")

result
## [1] "1000 this is 2000 test 3000 string"
```

Answer (score 3):

one way:

```
> cs <- strsplit(string," ")[[1]]
> cs[cs == "100"] <- replacement
> cat(cs)
1000 this is 2000 test 3000 string
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way (need change `replacement` to a list):

```
string <- c("100 this is 100 test 100 string")
replacement <- list(1000, 2000, 3000)
result <- do.call(sprintf, c(gsub('100', '%d', string), replacement))
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but `regmatches` has a `regmatches(...) <- value` assignment function which allows you to do this sort of thing cleanly in a one liner:

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr("100",string)) <- list(replacement)
string
# [1] "1000 this is 2000 test 3000 string"
```

If you don't want to overwrite your original `string`, you could call the function directly via:

```
`regmatches<-`(string, gregexpr("100",string), value=list(replacement))
#[1] "1000 this is 2000 test 3000 string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with `strsplit` :

```
split <- unlist(strsplit(string, "100", fixed=TRUE))
split <- split[nchar(split) > 0]
paste0(replacement, split, collapse="")
# [1] "1000 this is 2000 test 3000 string"
```

The second line is here because `strsplit` add an empty string at the beginning of its results because `100` appears in the first position.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `sub` and `*apply`

```
tail(sapply(replacement, function(x) {string <<- sub("\\b100\\b",x,string)}), 1)
```