# Replace substrings with elements from a vector

Tags: regex, r

I have a very long `string` (not a `vector` of `string`s, just one `string`). I would like to find a certain `substring` that occurs many times within the `string` and replace it with that `substring`, plus elements from a `character vector`. I would like to do this so that the first `substring` is replaced by the first `element` of the `vector` and the second `substring` is replced by the second element etc.

For example for input:

```
Stg<-c("cat fish dog cat fish dog cat fish dog cat fish dog")
Vec<-c(" one"," two"," red"," blue")
```

I would like to find "cat" and replace it with "cat" plus the data from `Vec` so the output would be

```
"cat one fish dog cat two fish dog cat red fish dog cat blue fish dog"
```

However, in my real `string` the text I am looking for is scattered everywhere (not a regular number of characters or words or anything between instances).

There seem to be several ways of doing this from `strigr` or `stringi` that will yield 4 vectors, each replacing with a different member of `Vec` but I am looking for just one stirng as an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `regmatches<-`:

```
regmatches(Stg,gregexpr("cat",Stg)) <- list(paste0("cat",Vec))
Stg
#[1] "cat one fish dog cat two fish dog cat red fish dog cat blue fish dog"
```

This is very similar to a previous question here: [Replacing elements of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081905/replacing-elements-of-a-vector)

If you don't want to overwrite the original `Stg` vector, use this code:

```
`regmatches<-`(Stg, gregexpr("cat",Stg), value=list(paste0("cat",Vec)))
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for the dup - I searched but it did not come up.

Comment: Or `regmatches(Stg, gregexpr('cat\\K', Stg, perl=T)) <- list(Vec)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a less cool approach now that I see @thelatemail's answer:

```
word <- "cat"
do.call(sprintf, c(list(gsub(word, "%s", Stg)), paste0(word, Vec)))

## [1] "cat one fish dog cat two fish dog cat red fish dog cat blue fish dog"
```

Comment: +1 @thelatemail gets the win, but getting a better understanding of `sprintf` is a nice bonus.